# Wait for a function ending to continue the program in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, return, wait

I'm implementing kmeans in Python and I'm looping the part where I move centroids until there's no movement, but the comparation of lCentroides and lCentroidesPrevious returns True  even if they are going to be different, because the main function doesn't wait until repartePixelesEnClusters() function ends (and reassign lCentroides), so both of them are the same. Here's the code:

```
def main():
    lCentroidesPrevious = []
    while centroidesIguales == False:   
        infoClusters = initInfoClusters()
        lCentroides, infoClusters = repartePixelesEnClusters(lCentroides, infoClusters) 
        centroidesIguales = lCentroides == lCentroidesPrevious
        lCentroidesPrevious = lCentroides
```

Any tips? I've read something with threads, but I don't want to use them... Is there another way?

Comment: I think the key here is in the `repartePixelesEnClusters` as the default python behavious is to be sequential. That is to say that the code shouldn't continue until the function called finished. Which means that that function surely does something weird and must have a way to indicate when it has finished

Comment: Are you using any threading/multiprocessing? It doesn't appear that you are. If you aren't than that's not the issue.

Comment: @Toote The problem is that the comparation it's done before the function is finished, so 'lCentroides' has the same value as the previous iteration.

Comment: @JoelCornett I suppose I'm not using any threadin/multiprocessing, I have only one core, and I haven't implemented anything about threading.

Comment: @AlejandroSanzDíaz you may not be doing it yourself, but the function `repartePixelesEnClusters` is probably doing so. The fact that it ends its computation without actually returning values is, once again, weird as if it were any function whatsoever what you are experiencing wouldn't happen.

Comment: @AlejandroSanzDíaz: 1) It's very difficult to figure out what's going on here without seeing the code for the rest of the functions. Can you provide some context -- either some code or just an explanation of the return types/vals of each function? 2) Unless one of your functions has implemented multi-threading/processing, your code will never execute "out of order". Each function already "waits" until the last one is done before it executes.